# Why is $c(t_i) ≥ c(t_p)$ in this matroid theorem proof?

Tags: optimization, matroids

In the proof of theorem 5.2 here [https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18453S17/matroid-notes.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egoemans/18453S17/matroid-notes.pdf) ,

> Since $c(t_i) ≥ c(t_p) > c(s_p)$, ti should have been selected when it was considered

Why is $c(t_i) ≥ c(t_p)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Needs to share own approach to the question.

Comment: Please give sufficient context. What is $c$, what are $t_i$ and $t_p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was being stupid and it is simple because $T_k$ is ordered non-increasing